# Regex to match n-quoted string

Tags: regex

It's fairly easy to match a string with escape sequences:

```
"(\\.|[^"])*"
```

But what if I wanted to support not only Python's triple-quoted strings (`"""hello"""`) but strings with any number of quotes as long as the start matches the end?

```
("+)(.*?)\1
```

Will do that, but I lose support for escape-sequences, as in `"hello\"world"` should match in its entirety.

Other examples that should fully match:

- `"""hello world"""""` (the string ends with two quotes)
- `""hello\""world""` (there are two quotes in the middle but one of them is escaped and the other isn't sufficient to end the string on its own)

Is this is even possible with regexes?

Comment: did you want to match `hello\"world` in this `"hello\"world"` string? Which part do you want to match in this `""hello\""world""` string?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The entire thing, including the quotes. I can add more capturing groups later if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
^("+)((.*?)(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\1$
```

I had a simpler expression earlier, but it failed on `"hello world \\"`, so I've updated with lookbehinds that allow for the presence of an even number of backslashes before the closing quotes, but disallow an odd number of backslashes. Regex syntax used is PCRE.

Fiddle [here](http://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/3).

Comment: Aw man, that's really close but you cheated with the `^$` anchors. If you take those off then it matches `"""hello world"""""` as two separate strings instead of one. It should be greedy... I think. That makes more sense, right?

Comment: @Mark If you're not trying to parse a number of these instances out of a body of text, greedy should be fine. Otherwise, good luck to the person trying to come up with a non-greedy variant :-)

Comment: It's going into a parser. The start is anchored, but the end isn't. That's a bummer. I'll give this some more thought but I might have to toss this feature out; just thought it would be fun.

Answer (score 0):

This expression matches all yours examples:

```
("+)(.*[\\"]?.*?)+?\1
```

see: http://regex101.com/r/jW8iV8/1

Comment: It *shouldn't* match `"hello world\"` -- the ending quote is escaped.